# replacing pos kitchen printer keeping the rs 232 in place converting both ends to ethernet

Tags: adapter, rs232

I am replacing kitchen printers that run on what I believe is RS232 cabling with a 25 pin plug into the printer.  On the other end at the terminal it is terminated with a 9 pin plug to an ethernet adapter.  The new printers are network printers connected by ethernet.  I want to leave the current cabling in place and at the printer take the 25 pin off and replace it with a 9 pin then run through an ethernet adapter to the new printer.  Can I leave the cabling in place to achieve this with the correct male and female adapter parts?  The cabling is 5 or 6 wires, maybe 8 if they cut the ones NOT used when I took the 25 pin connector apart to inspect it.  I can't remember how many wires are in the cabling.  I understand ethernet but not this cabling...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can re-terminate DB25 to DB9 (no guarantee on colors though):

[image: DB9-25 pinout]

If you're going to get new ends for existing cables though, then you might as well just get cheap adapters and not worry about the cabling at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not likely.   Older parallel printers use a 25 pin connector.  However, if its going to a 9 pin connector, I doubt that it is parallel.  That sounds like a serial connection.   That being said, I dont understand how its being connected to an ethernet connector.  Unless it IS a serial connector and it doesnt need more than 9 pins.   The best solution is to check your printers manual and/or contact their support.  Something is not adding up.